# How to assign a type to the datetime variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I need to assign the type to a `datetime` variable based on the following rules. If the `datetime` belongs to the date intervals of `Type1`, then the type is `Type1`. The same logic is applied to `Type2` and `Type3`.

```
Type1
01/01/17 - 07/04/17
18/04/17 - 25/05/17
01/10/17 - 22/12/17

Type2
08/04/17 - 17/04/17
26/05/17 - 30/06/17
27/08/17 - 30/09/17
23/12/17 - 31/12/17

Type3
01/07/17 - 26/08/17
```

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime("2017-04-10 11:00:34.0", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The value of `dt` should correspond to the type `Type2`. Is there any way to implement this task in Python 2.7 without using an extensive number of `if then` rules?

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't understand those "types"… please clarify.

Comment: @deceze: If the `datetime` belongs to the date intervals of `Type1`, then the type is `Type1`. The same logic is applied to `Type2` and `Type3`.

Comment: Is see, so you just want to formulate some condition `if t1 <= dt <= t2: type = 1 ...`, but preferably without doing a lot of `if..elif`?

Comment: @deceze: Right. Maybe using a dictionary or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rough sketch of how this can be structured:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

types = {
    'type1': (
        (date(2017, 1, 1), date(2017, 4, 7)),
        ...
    ),
    ...
}

dt = datetime.strptime('2017-04-10 11:00:34.0', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
the_type = None    

for t, ranges in types.items():
    for start, end in ranges:
        if start <= dt.date() <= end:
            the_type = t
            break

    if the_type is not None:
        break
```

Comment: Is it possible to maintain the same approach if I want to skip the year. In other words, if the year is not important.

Comment: Then you don't store `date` objects but maybe just `(day, month)` tuples and simply adjust the comparison.

Comment: I did as you recommended. The comparison is done as follows: `if date(dt.year,start(0),start(1)) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end(0),end(1)):`, but it gives error saying that start and end are numbers. How can they be numbers if I just deleted `date` from types, so they should be tuples.